# Powershell: Out-gridview with text files

Tags: powershell, text-files, out-gridview

I have two text files, let's say containing:

1.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

2.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I'm trying to read the files, then output the results to Out-Gridview (each file in it's own column) :

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
```

I'm trying :

```
$list1= gc 1.txt 
$list2= gc 2.txt



$list1 | Add-Member -Name "LIST 2" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $liste2


$list1 | out-gridview -wait
```

But all i get is :

[image]

How can i have each text file read then output to columns in gridview? Thank you so much I can't figure this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hashtable when you only have two columns.
Like that:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4
$b = "a","b","c","d"
$hashtable = @{}

for($i = 0;$a.Count -gt $i;$i++){
    $hashtable.Add($a[$i],$b[$i])
}

$hashtable | Out-GridView
```

if you have more than two columns,create a custom object

Comment: Thank you, i've decided to use a different way but this is helpful!